# Magento 2: Automatically maintenance mode

Tags: magento2

We have several stores running on EKS (Kubernetes) and for some reason one of the stores enter on maintenance mode for no reason:
`Unable to proceed: the maintenance mode is enabled.`

We are using Magento Enterprise 2.3.1.
There is no one going into the containers to enable maintenance mode, even when there is no code deploy or users using the stores (this is a stage environment) the maintenance mode appears.
When we have the OPs team take a look at the `var/.maintenance.flag`, the file was created by root and sometimes it takes time to be deleted.
Looking at the logs I can see that sometimes the store will throw errors for an hour or just a few minutes.

Has anyone been affected by this? It looks like schedule backups and `setup:upgrade` commands can create the flag, but these are not running when the flag is created.

Thanks.

Comment: maybe there is a cron running that does the db / code backup that sets the maintenance mode before running?

Comment: @Marius, no. We use Kubernetes scheduler to run the cron, so every minute we start a container and run the command:
`magento cron:run`

And when I look at the logs it's all normal:



`kubectl logs magento-cron-5151561-t9fj5 -n MYSTORE
Executing magento cron:run at MYSTORE:magento-465116x-1234
Ran jobs by schedule.`

Comment: As created by root that would suggest it's being created within the container.  Maybe you know this.  But to me that rules out anything malicious

Comment: That's the thing, no one is going into the container to run this, only 4 people have access to the container.
We created a symlink `/usr/bin/magento -> /var/www/html/bin/magento`
`/usr/bin/magento` is owned by root, but the bin/magento file is owned by www-data, so it shouldn't be that one creating the maintenance flag.

Comment: we also have the same kind of issue and the reason was DB backup. so please check once that/

Comment: @RizwanKhan, no. There is no DB backup enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found out the issue.
When running on Kubernetes, we run an initial check to make sure the store exists. We were checking the DB, but we were having several issues with DNS using AWS EKS.
So when the pod would initialize, it would try to connect to the DB and fail. Then our script would think that Magento wasn't installed and tried to install again. It would fail, but the first step of installation is to put on maintenance mode. As the installation would fail, it would never remove from maintenance mode.

We are using something else to check if a store is up or not. Also making sure the error doesn't trigger when it really doesn't have to.